# Bootstrap5 modal error when using with anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have created a anchor tag with a trash icon which trigger the delete modal. Which have to button yes or no which futher hits their respective apis.
Below is part of a react component:

```
<a
   data-testid="deleteEventModalBtn"
   className={styles.icon}
   data-bs-toggle="modal"
   data-bs-target={`#deleteEventModal${props.id}`}
   >
   <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
 </a>

 <div
   className="modal fade"
   id={`deleteEventModal${props.id}`}
   tabIndex={-1}
   role="dialog"
   aria-labelledby={`deleteEventModalLabel${props.id}`}
   aria-hidden="true"
  >
  <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
           <h5
             className="modal-title"
             id={`deleteEventModalLabel${props.id}`}
            >
             {t('deleteEvent')}
             </h5>
             <Button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </Button>
        </div>
       <div className="modal-body">{t('deleteEventMsg')}</div>
     <div className="modal-footer">
              <Button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-danger"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                {t('no')}
              </Button>
              <Button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-success"
                onClick={deleteEvent}
                data-testid="deleteEventBtn"
              >
                {t('yes')}
              </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I am getting some error regarding bootstrap when i click on the trash icon.

```
ERROR
ne.getInstance(...) is null
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js/</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:147739:13
i@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:146670:53
```

Can anyone help me?

I was expecting to get get the delete modal but when i click on the trash icon it gives me the above error.

Answer (score 0):

you still can use , and decorate it with a great css.

Please check this documentation for some great examples
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/